# Why is the switch operator only reading default and not the other instructions

Tags: c

I am working on an exercise:

> You have a  matrix written in a file and given some commands you have to shift
> (left or right) or (up or down) in a circular way a certain row or column and after given the instructions you print it out.

This is my code so far. The problem is that it is like the `switch` operator is not reading anything. It is just printing "Exiting" which is in the `default` block.

I know that it is far from done but I just need a bit of help with my problem.

To be clear, I only need help with why the `switch` statement isn't working. I want to try to solve the rest of the problem myself. I just need help with that specific part.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#define N 30

int main()
{
    int v[N][N];
    int i=0,p,j=0;
    int command1;
    int command2;
    int times;
    int times2=0;
    FILE*file;
    file=fopen("file","r");
    if(file==NULL)
    {
        printf("ERROR in the file....");
        exit(1);
    }
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            fscanf(file,"%d ",&v[i][j]);
        }
    }

    printf("Original Matrix: \n");
    for(i=0; i<3; i++)
    {
        for(j=0; j<3; j++)
        {
            printf("%d ",v[i][j]);
        }
        printf("\n");
    }

    printf("\n\n");
    printf("Choose:\n1:Rows\n2:Columns\n3:Exiting\n");
    {
        scanf("%d",&command1);
    }

    switch (command1)
    {
    case '1':
    {
        printf("Choose:\n1:Shift left\n2:Shift right\n");
        scanf("%d",&command2);
        if(command2==1)
        {
            printf("Which row:\n");
            scanf("%d",&p);
            printf("\n");
            printf("How many times:\n");
            scanf("%d",&times);
            while(times2<times && i<3)
            {
                v[p][i]= v[p][i+1];
                v[p][i+1]=v[p][i+2];
                v[p][i+2]=v[p][i];

                i++;
                times2++;
            }
            printf("\nNew Matrix:\n");
            for(i=0; i<3; i++)
            {
                for(j=0; j<3; j++)
                {
                    printf("%d ",&v[i][j]);
                }
                printf("\n");
            }

        }
    }
    break;
    case '2':
    {
        printf("Something Something");
    }
    default:
        printf("\nExiting");
    }

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You're also not checking the return value from `scanf()` so you don't really know if you've actually read any input.

Comment: Oh damn. I was looking up at some previous examples and they used the ' '. So you use    ' ' only for character commands right?

Comment: @JohnKugelman: I reformated to improve readability, especially fixing lack of horizontal space. I hope I did not offend anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Make that `case 1:` and `case 2:` without any single quotes. When you use `'1'` and `'2'` it's checking for `char`s, but `command1` is an `int`.

Make sure to add a `break;` statement to the second case as well so it doesn't fall through to the `default:` case.

Comment: No need to apologize. It's a common mistake and the C language is partially to blame for its conflation of ints and chars. There are other languages where this would be a compile error.

Comment: You might also mention the problem in `fscanf(file,"%d ",&v[i][j]);`

Comment: Help me out? I'm blind, I don't see it.

Comment: no problem that I can see.